# Is it possible to use Unity's application menu with GNOME-Shell?

Tags: unity, gnome, appmenu

Despite many ppl. dislike the approach of Unity using its panel to show all the menus, I like it and would like to use it with GNOME-Shell. Is there any way to use it with GNOME-Shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Here is a page with complete instructions:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/get-global-menu-in-gnome-shell.html

Though it doesn't work as good as in Unity yet so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Messed up my system (on some occasions eg. the wlan password dialog a unity and a gnome window are opend simultaniously), so I would not recommend it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :( you should probably wait for a stable release before attempting this again.

Comment: But isn't that ‘globalmenu’ rather than ‘appmenu’? Will it work with the Firefox and LibreOffice extensions? I think their extensions are only appmenu compatible, so Gnome Shell needs to provide appmenu compatibility or rewrite those extensions.